# An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake gRPC Microservices .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, microservices, grpc

I have trying to run two connected gRPC microservices in my laptop localhost. The two microservices are WorkflowService and UserManagementService. WorkflowService run in port 44394. UserManagementService run in port 44322.The WorkflowService need to hit UserManagementService in `processhistory` API. I tried to hit `processhistory` API with Postman but I got following message:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: The request was aborted. IOException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake. IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.. SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The request was aborted.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ReadFrameAsync(Boolean initialFrame)
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ProcessIncomingFramesAsync()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ProcessIncomingFramesAsync()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendHeadersAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean mustFlush)
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Shared.TelemetryHeaderHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)")
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpClientCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at UserManagementService.Protos.GetUserDataGrpcService.GetUserDataGrpcServiceClient.GetUserData(GetUserDataRequest request, CallOptions options) in C:\Users\s.janaka\source\repos\vip-pln\MS-WorkflowService\WorkflowService\obj\Debug\net5.0\Protos\Get-user-dataGrpc.cs:line 98
   at UserManagementService.Protos.GetUserDataGrpcService.GetUserDataGrpcServiceClient.GetUserData(GetUserDataRequest request, Metadata headers, Nullable`1 deadline, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\s.janaka\source\repos\vip-pln\MS-WorkflowService\WorkflowService\obj\Debug\net5.0\Protos\Get-user-dataGrpc.cs:line 94
   at WorkflowService.Adaptor.UserManagementServiceAdaptor.GetUserByUserId(Int32 userId, HttpContext context) in C:\Users\s.janaka\source\repos\vip-pln\MS-WorkflowService\WorkflowService\Adaptor\UserManagementServiceAdaptor.cs:line 46
   at WorkflowService.Authorization.JwtMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IUserManagementServiceAdaptor userManagementAdaptor, ICustomAuthenticationHelperUtility authenticationUtils) in C:\Users\s.janaka\source\repos\vip-pln\MS-WorkflowService\WorkflowService\Authorization\JwtMiddleware.cs:line 30
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

What I already tried is to enforce trust ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate by executing following command in command prompt:

`dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

But I still got the same message in Postman. What am I doing wrong?. Please help me, I need to run the connected microservices in my laptop in order to debug the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i don't think it is do with certificate. how did you called grpc API with Postman ?

Comment: @CodingMytra I hit the endpoint with postman

Comment: @CodingMytra not yet

Comment: may i was not clear with my question. how do you call an grpc api with postman. can you put an example in your question ?

Comment: I think I need to change the word. I did not 'call' an grpc API with Postman. But I test an grpc API with Postman. @CodingMytra

Answer (score -1):

My problem was solved. Turns out there is a setting that I have to adjust for `ServiceConfig` setting in the `appsettings.json`

Comment: A little bit more information could help the community.